# awk to store values under keyword in variable from file

Tags: awk

I am trying to use `awk` to print all lines under a specific word, `Label`, to the variable `$var`. In this example, there are two values, but that won't always be the case (it will be different each time), but the word will always be the same and in the same position. My two attempts execute but `echo` the row in which the word was found.

**file**

```
[Header]                                
Name    1                                                   

[ID]                                
1
1                               

[ID1]                               

[Info]                              
Label   xxx
1,,,,xxx
2,,,,yyy
```

**awk 1**

```
var=$(awk -vvar="Label" '($1 == var) {print $0}' file)
echo "$var"

Label   xxx
```

**awk 2**

```
var=$(awk '/Label/{for(i=0;i<1;i++){print;getline}}' file)
echo "$var"

Label   xxx
```

**desired**

```
echo "$var"
1
2
```

Comment: "there are two values, but that wont always be the case" - so how does the output stop? end of file?

Comment: yes, it will be the end of the file... that is there will be nothing below the 2 (or whatever the value is). Thank you :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variable - in the example I've called it `p`. Set the variable once the label is found. From the next line onwards, print the line.

```
var=$(awk 'p==1{print} /Label/{p=1}' file)
```

Or using a variable to store "Label" search string:

```
var=$(awk -vlab="Label" 'p==1{print} $1==lab{p=1}' file)
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)...

Comment: I made a typo in the input file and updated the post. There are , in each line and the current output 1,,,,xxx 2,,,,yyy. Do I need an RS to separate each record to have the desired output? Thank you :)

Comment: Figured it out needed `var=$(awk -F, 'p==1{print $1} /Label/{p=1}' file)`. Thank you :).

Comment: Missed your comment, glad you worked it out